# How to create a form with list submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I'm trying to make a form question where people can enter a list of 1-10 things.
Then, the questions after that will ask for an explanation (text box) for each item on the list. I'm running into an issue on how to do those things dynamically.

I know for a single question:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input id="choice1" type="text" name="item1" placeholder="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

Or if they were going to list two things:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input id="choice1" type="text" name="item1" placeholder="" />
    <input id="choice2" type="text" name="item2" placeholder="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

Then a follow-up question would be:

```
<h3 class="fs-subtitle">Explain why {listChoice1} is on your list</h3>
    <textarea id="explanation1" type="text" name="explanation1"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button next" value="Next" />
```

But what's a way I can cleanly allow them to increase the list size to what they want, and then dynamically have a follow-up question for each thing on the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a template and then use `cloneNode` and keep track of the index.

```js
var indexForm = 1;
var submit = document.querySelector("input[name='submit']");

submit.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  //first add explanation
  var div = document.querySelector("div.template");
  var title = div.children[1].cloneNode(true); //use true here to copy textnode too!
  var textarea = div.children[2].cloneNode();
  
  //change the values
  title.innerHTML = title.innerHTML.replace("{listChoice}", document.querySelector("#choice"+indexForm).value);
  textarea.id = "explanation" + indexForm;
  textarea.name = "explanation" + indexForm;
  
  //add the explanation to the DOM
  //select the input submit
  submit.parentNode.insertBefore(title, submit);
  submit.parentNode.insertBefore(textarea, submit);
  
  //add 1 to indexForm
  indexForm++;
  //add new input
  var newinput = div.children[0].cloneNode();
  newinput.id = "choice" + indexForm;
  newinput.name = "choice" + indexForm;
  submit.parentNode.insertBefore(newinput, submit);
  
  
  //do not execute form
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
div.hidden {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform">
    <input id="choice1" type="text" name="item1" placeholder="" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" />
</form>

<div class="template hidden">
<input id="choice_template" type="text" name="item" placeholder="" />
<h3 class="fs-subtitle">Explain why {listChoice} is on your list</h3>
    <textarea id="explanation_template" type="text" name="explanation"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I would say that on input `blur` you can check whether your input has a value. If it has a value, you can use `insertAfter` in jQuery to add a textarea after the input, asking for an explanation.

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="item1" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

With the following 4 lines of jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  /* if you leave a text input field */
  $('body').on('blur', 'input[type="text"]', function(e){
    /* and the next item is not a textarea and this input is not empty */
    if(!$(this).next().is('textarea') && $(this).val() != '') {
      /* create a textarea with a somewhat similar name */
      var textarea = "<textarea name='textarea_"+$(this).attr('name')+"' placeholder='Explain why this is on your list'></textarea>";
      /* and insert it after this item */
      $( textarea ).insertAfter( this );
    }
  });
});
```

While you are doing that, you might as well add another text input for their next thing in the list (if they want to add that), with the following 6 lines of jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  /* if you leave a text input field */
  $('body').on('blur', 'input[type="text"]', function(e){
    /* and the next item is not a textarea and this input is not empty */
    if(!$(this).next().is('textarea') && $(this).val() != '') {
      /* create a textarea with a somewhat similar name */
      var textarea = "<textarea name='textarea_"+$(this).attr('name')+"' placeholder='Explain why this is on your list'></textarea>";
      /* and insert it after this item */
      $( textarea ).insertAfter( this );
      /* create a new text input */
      var newinput = "<input name='item"+(parseInt($(this).attr('name').substring(4))+1)+"' type='text' />";
      /* and insert it before the submit button */
      $( newinput ).insertBefore( $("input[type='submit']") );
    }
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OjmaxY/?editors=1010

This solution requires only 1 form, requires only 6 lines of jQuery and does not use CSS.